# Unnecessary backslash characters added when hyperlinking code block with brackets `[]`

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, code-block, character-escaping

While writing a post, if the hyperlink tool is used on a code block containing `[` or `]`, the tool will add extraneous backslash `\` characters in front of the brackets.

Example:  `user:351462 [support]` -> [`user:351462 \[support\]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user:351462%20[support]).

[image: Gif demonstrating addition of extra backslash characters]